# Catchy phrase to express or mean "always in stock/no back orders etc"

Tags: phrases

I'm looking for a neat phrase to coin the message of 'we're never out of stock of a product' or 'We always ship all of your order, no back orders' etc.

Best I can come up with so far myself, is, 'Delivered In Full'.

Comment: ELU is not a good resource for style suggestions.

Comment: Not delivery-specific, but: "Ready when you are"?

Comment: I agree with Mitch.  The question is also ambitious.  What you are describing though is along the line of "we always fulfil orders" or "100% order fulfilment".

Comment: "When one widget leaves our inventory, two more take its place."

Comment: Hire a copywriter. I know one ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like ***"All orders fulfilled"*** (borrowing slightly from @Sam's comment).  I am pretty sure this covers what you are asking for.

Comment: Even better, _"All orders fulfilled immediately"_

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "readily available" or "freely available".

To me, that suggests it's ready upon demand.